# Android ViewPager - OutOfMemory Exception using Glide (on phones and on TV)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter, android-glide

I'm using `ViewPager` in my app for showing pictures (from camera, etc. so it can be large pictures). Also I'm using `Glide library` for loading pictures from `Uri` to `ImageView`. This is my `PagerAdapter`:

```
public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

   private List<FileMetaData> mPhotos = null;
   private Context _context;
   private LayoutInflater _inflater;

   public GalleryPagerAdapter(Context context, List<FileMetaData> files) {
      _context = context;
      mPhotos = files;
      _inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
      return mPhotos.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
      View itemView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_pager_item, container, false);
      container.addView(itemView);

      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhotoDetail);

      Glide.with(_context).load(mPhotos.get(position).getUri()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
            /*.skipMemoryCache(true).*/.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(imageView);

      return itemView;
   }

   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ImageView i = (ImageView) object;
      container.removeView(i);
   }
}
```

Layout `photo_pager_item` is simple:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPhotoDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And `setOffscreenPageLimit` is set to 1 (by default). My problem is that I'm getting `OutOfMemory Exception`. But I don't know how to solve it. What should I change? How can I recycle images loaded by Glide? And I need to make it work also on TV (big screen).

Comment: post the errors from the Logcat -- try another library like http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: cant you resize the bitmap before loading into imageVIew doesn't Glide have a function like `resize(width,height)` in its builder pattern?

Comment: Change the `diskCacheStrategy` to `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` and remove target when the imageview is destroyed from the adapter with `Glide.clear(imageView);`

Comment: In addition to @NikolaDespotoski's suggestion. Also you could use `Glide.get(this).clearMemory();` in the `onLowMemory()` callback of the activity / fragment hosting your viewpager

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Thanks for your suggestions. I tried it but I still get OOM Exception. Log: http://pastebin.com/BnyMEB8c

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I'm getting OutOfMemory Exception. But I don't know
>   how to solve it. What should I change? How can I recycle images loaded
>   by Glide? And I need to make it work also on TV (big screen).

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. if you are getting `OutOfMemory Exception`  This usually comes when your memory buffer size becomes full let say in case if you are displaying large size images in devices which are having low memory.

Possible solutions can be :

**1.** As you are saying you are loading the image view from the URL. Downloading 1080*1920 size of image for the device of 480*800 is not the right way to do. So, try to make several images in you backend like small(300*300), medium(500*500),large(1000*1000), original(XXX*XXX)

Afterwords, according to the device's current resolution fetch the appropriate image from url.

**2.** If your image are not having transparency try to use **JPEG** file instead of **PNGs**

Obviously, you will need to do some extra efforts but this would help you to minimize the 'OutOfMemory Exception'. However, after this as well there are many scenarios due to which you can face this exception.

I hope it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Ad 1) The images are stored in device storage. (I'm not downloading it from URL now). I'm using Uri because they can be stored in SD card or External storage. But with more image sizes you are right. Ad 2) Most of the images should be JPG or JPEG (because they are photos from camera).

Answer (score 0):

After profiling the an app, I found a memory leak using the above method. This worked for me using Glide and a viewpager:

```
  Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageURL))
                    .asBitmap()
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {

                            if (bitmap != null) {

                                imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

                            }
                        }
                    });
```